# GTK 3 setup: Procedure entry point deflateSetHeader could not be located DLL libgio-2.0.0.dll

Tags: windows, gtk, zlib

I am attempting to set up GTK3 for development on Windows 10 following the instructions on [tarnyko.net](http://www.tarnyko.net/repo/gtk3_build_system/tutorial/gtk3_tutorial.htm)
using the 64bit 3.6.4 bundle from [here](http://www.tarnyko.net/dl/gtk.htm). The test program currently builds without errors, using the generated options. When I run the program a dialog appears displaying the error message:

> Procedure entry point deflateSetHeader could not be located in the
>   synamic link library C:\Gtk\bin\libgio-2.0.0.dll

From what I can tell so far, deflateSetHeader is a function in zlib that was not present in older versions - a possible cause for the error. Looking in the header file of zlib that came with Gtk, it lists the function.
I have copies of zlib1 in my Gtk bin dir and MinGW (GCC v7.2.0) bin dir.

I tried swapping the versions between directories, but no joy. Don't have much else in my environment path variable, except for a vanilla Python 3.6 install. Don't have zlib1 in SysWOW64. I tried adding `-lzlib1` to my gcc compiler options, but that didn't seem to make a difference. I'm running out of ideas now.

Anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

Found the cause by searching my C drive for zlib and found a copy in
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin that was causing the problem.